# I am not sure how to get this to pass for true and not true

Tags: ruby

I am not sure how to get this to pass so true or false will come back depending on if the array has content or not.

```
def no_fruits?(a)
  [].empty? 
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the parameter you passed in to the method rather than using a new instance of Array (`[]`) in the method.

```
def no_fruits?(a)
  a.nil? or a.empty?
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I was spending forever trying to figure that out lol.

Comment: @JoelScalera If this helps, please kindly accept the answer :)